# How do I specify editing a DWORD in decimal when writing a .reg file?

Tags: registry

I'm making a little batch program that edits screensavers by making a reg file and opening it. However, I need the `.reg` file to known that these values will be in decimal, not the default hex. Is there anyway to do this?

BTW.
The answer has to use the `.reg` format, not batch; therfore the answer must not contain batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try converting your decimal entry into hexadecimal and put that in the registry using `reg add`. Use something like this:

```
set decentry=%YOUR DECIMAL ENTRY%
call cmd /c exit /b %decentry%
set hexentry=%exitcode%
reg add ROOTKEY\Subkey /v VALUENAME /t REG_DWORD /d %hexentry% /f
```

What this program does, it takes the string `%YOUR DECIMAL ENTRY%` that you provide and converts it from your decimal format to hex. Then it overwrites the previous registry entry with the hex.

I hope this is what you were looking for. I didn't quite understand what you meant by wanting the answer in .reg format.

Comment: I mean this should not use batch; just a .reg file.

Comment: I do not know how the solution would only use a .reg file. The way I know it, you use the .bat file to control how you write to your .reg file. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 9):

Not what you want to hear, but if you are using a .REG file, you must/can only specify the values for REG_DWORD in hex.

You can set the value in decimal using the REG ADD command, but that is clearly not what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are correct in that there is no way to specify a DWORD value in decimal, only in hex.

To set a DWORD in a .reg file, use this syntax:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[Full\Path\To\Key]
"KeyName"=dword:abc123
```

Note that the value after `dword:` is always interpreted as hex even though it does not (and can not) have the common hex prefix "0x".